# Deploy smart contract with web3 and ganache-cli

Tags: web3js, ganache-cli

I've been trying to get a simple contract deployed on ganache with web3.js.
Here is my test code :

```
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const provider = ganache.provider()
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const { abi, evm } = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let myContract;

before(async function() {

    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()

    myContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
        .deploy({data: "0x" + evm.bytecode.object, arguments: []})
        .send({from: accounts[0], gas: 5000000});

    console.log("finished")

});
// describe and it part....
```

The error is : `Callback was already called : 
at ....../ganache-cli/build/lib.node.js:22953:36`

Anybody got any idea?
Thanks a lot

Comment: The `before` clause is not executed when there are no `it` clauses, so there cannot be any error here. Please share the relevant code, and indicate exactly which line is throwing the given error.

Comment: actually there is an "it" clause right where i spotted ( commented out). the problem is with send method. the moment it gets called booom.. Error : Callback was already called

Comment: How do you know it's in the `send` method, when it is appended to two other function calls preceding it (`new` and `deploy`)?

Comment: Of course i don't know for sure. But the result of deploy is just a TransactionObject with some method on it (send, call,...). I'm guessing the issue is raised when the real sending is happening so there has to be some sort of callback.!!!!

Comment: I've been following this link : https://medium.com/coinmonks/get-started-with-building-ethereum-dapps-and-smart-contracts-d86b9f7bd1c. Except using async/await

Comment: When version of ganache-cli are you using?

Comment: ganache-cli : 6.0.3 -- solc : 0.4.19 -- web3 : 1.0.0-beta.26 -- mocha : 4.0.1

Comment: You're using extremely old versions, and I think, also a pretty old reference (which you've linkd in one of the comments above). First off, you can use Truffle in order to build Mocha tests which interact with Ganache. If you do so, then there's no need to use all of the constants at the beginning of your script. You have `web3` and `artifacts` given to you as global objects, and you can use them for an easy contract deployment plus interaction with the provider. Second, I recommend that you by the least upgrade to ganache-cli v6.7.0, solc v0.4.26 and web3 v1.2.6.

Comment: You can read more about Truffle [here](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/overview).

Comment: NP. P.S.: Both Mocha and Web3 come along with Truffle, so if you choose to use it then there's no need to install them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Change your node version I have seen this error before you need to set to compatible version in my case it was v12.

https://cryptoyaks.com/callback-was-already-called-ganache/